# Hibernate exception in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, constraintexception

I am handling a constraint exception in a Grails application. It's a Hibernate constraint issue while doing a bulk load of data.

I want to just skip over this and keep processing, but after a few more DB interactions, the application fails terminally. I presume that the database session object is in an unknown state.

Is there anything I can do in the handler to reset the session?

Comment: have you tried a stateless session? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession

Comment: if your bulk process is simple enough, you should use `groovy.sql.Sql` w/o involving hibernate